# SSRS line chart count when date not null breaks only if there are future dates

Tags: date, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2017

I have a line chart created that displays the counts of rowIDs grouped by the month of an associated date. However, not every row has the date. If there is no date, I don't want it counted at all. My current semi-fix for this is adding a filter in the category group properties that excluded dates earlier than 1/1/1960. I tried "IsNothing(Date) <> true" type filters but they didn't work. I am guessing in the background the NULL dates are getting translated to 1/1/1900 or something.

With the Date > 1960 filter it works as I want, doesn't count any rows w/ NULL dates, almost. If any of the dates are in the future, specifically the next month, then all the NULL dates get counted in that month. If the date is more than 1 month in the future then no NULLs are counted, although the line skips months with no dates. I tried forcing it to 0 for those months but it doesn't work. I would think that's because of the way I'm grouping on the associated date. Such a grouping results in

```
| Month | Count |
|-------|-------|
| 10/20 | 2     |
| 1/21  | 4     |
```

when what it needs is something like

```
| Month | Count |
|-------|-------|
| 10/20 | 2     |
| 11/20 |       |
| 12/20 |       |
| 1/21  | 4     |
```

Does anyone have any idea what's causing the NULLs to get counted in the next month? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do so that the 0 months will show up?

Comment: Hmm... the table works in the preview. Looks gross here though. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've edited the question to format the table correctly. Can you post a sample of data that gives the output you expect above. Also show any grouping in your report design and your dataset query.